# Query that returns all tables that don't contain a particular column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Here is the simple sql query that will return all tables that have the following column name, 'userid' or 'user_id'.

```
SELECT  t.name 
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE 'userid' OR c.name LIKE 'user_id'
ORDER BY name
```

However, what I would like to do here is to get all the tables that **don't contain** 'userid' column and 'user_id' column. How should I query this?

P.S. Using **NOT LIKE** will still bring back the table that contains 'userid' or 'user_id' column, if the table has some other different columns.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need "tables where no column userid/user_id exists"

```
SELECT
    t.name 
FROM 
    sys.tables t
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
          FROM sys.columns c
          WHERE t.object_id = c.object_id AND c.name IN ('userid', 'user_id'))
ORDER BY
    t.name
```

Edit:

You can also use your `original` query in an EXCEPT clause

```
SELECT t.name FROM sys.tables t
EXCEPT
SELECT t.name 
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE c.name IN  ('userid', 'user_id')
ORDER BY t.name
```

These two queries should give identical plans and performance

Comment: Thanks very much. They both worked pretty well. Nice use of EXCEPT, especially.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name from sys.tables 
WHERE name not in (
    SELECT  t.name 
    FROM sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    WHERE c.name LIKE 'userid' OR c.name LIKE 'user_id'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap it in a sub query

```
Select t2.Name
From sys.tables t2
Where t2.Name Not In 
(
    SELECT  t.name 
    FROM sys.tables t
    JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    WHERE c.name LIKE 'userid' OR c.name LIKE 'user_id'
)
ORDER BY t2.name
```